# Open Solidworks PDM directory from another program

Tags: c#, solidworks

I want to open/start a folder that is in Solidworks PDM from another application.

I'm using C# and use this code:

```cs
Process.Start(@"C:\Sandbox\Test");
```

The Sandbox directory is a View directory.
When I manually navigate to this directory it logs into the vault and view all directories as it should.

When I execute the above code I just get an explorer of the directory, but without PDM functionality.

Is there any way to be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conisio link that is handled when the PDM client is installed. The format of the link is like this;

`conisio://<vaultname>/<action>?projectid=<ProjectID>&documentid=<DocumentID>&objecttype=1`

`action` being `explore`.

You'll obviously need to know the folder/project ID, but you can use any document ID that is not deleted in the system. Just pass that string to `Process.Start()`.

`Process.Start("conisio://Sandbox/explore?projectid=1005&documentid=7543&objecttype=1");`

For reference, here are the other actions.

`Where:
<vaultname> is the name of the file vault
<ProjectID> is the database ProjectID of the folder where the file is located in the vault
<DocumentID> is the database DocumentID of the file
<action> is one of the following:
open          – Opens the file in associated application
view           – Opens the configured “Viewer” application for the file
explore      – Opens an explorer window in the folder the file resides and selects the file
get             – Triggers a Get of the file to the local file vault view
lock            – Checks out the file
properties  – Brings up the file properties
history        – Brings up the file history`